# Function call in wordpress short code handler fails

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I want to call a function I have written from a shortcode handler. I have now simplified the code but I cannot find out why this won't work:

```
public function handleShortcode($atts) {
    return X();
}

private function X()
{
    return 'Hi world';
}
```

but, if I try:

```
public function handleShortcode($atts) {
    return 'Hello World!';
}
```

it works.

This may be a dumb question but can anyone explain why the first example fails?

Comment: private function is not call in public function without class.

Comment: Have a look at this gist https://github.com/tommcfarlin/wp-gist/blob/master/src/classes/class-wp-gist-shortcode.php

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `X()`, but your `X()` function appears to be within a class. Presumably the same class as `handleShortcode()`. So you need to call it the normal way you call functions within a class:

```
public function handleShortcode($atts) {
    return $this->X();
}

private function X()
{
    return 'Hi world';
}
```

If you're not in a class at all, you need to get rid of the `private` and `public`:

```
function handleShortcode($atts) {
    return X();
}

function X()
{
    return 'Hi world';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm fairly new to php, after years in the c# world. Old habits...

Answer (score 0):

These look like methods of an object. If they are in the same object, use `$this->X()`, otherwise you will have to mimic ->X()'s behavior as you can't call a private method on an object.